# Como redirecionar a 'interface' para uma página inicial após um tempo de inatividade?

Tags: javascript, atualização, redirecionamento-de-url

Estou construindo uma interface interativa para um totem com HTML/CSS3 que irá funcionar offline, com os arquivos locais, sem localhost, usando o Chrome no modo "Kiosk" e implementei este script(costurado com a ajuda da net) para que após um tempo de inatividade, no mouse/touchscreen a interface volte para a página inicial, acontece que nada acontec, eu trabalho com HTML e CSS3, mas agora iniciei em programação e ainda sou iniciante, então onde eu errei?

```
var idleTime = 60000;

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 1) { // 20 minutes
        window.location.reload = "initial_page.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema do seu código está no `window.location.reload = "initial_page.html"`, da uma olhada na [documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) p/ saber melhor como o método funciona. O restante está funcionando bem, traduzi o código e coloquei alguns log's somente para ficar mais claro o que está acontecendo. Como @Derlei respondeu, utilize [`window.location.replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) para fazer o redirecionamento.

```js
var segundos = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Incrementa o tempo de inatividade
    var inatividade = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); 

    //Zera o tempo de inatividade
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        segundos = 0;
        console.log("Mouse movimentado.");
    });

    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        segundos = 0;
        console.log("Tecla pressionada.");
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    segundos++;
    console.log(segundos + " segundo(s) de inatividade.");
    if (segundos > 5) { 
        console.log("Redirecionando...");
        window.location.replace("initial_page.html");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Realmente estava desconfiando do window.location.reload(); obrigado pelo esclarecimento, vou verificar.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de:

```
    window.location.reload = "initial_page.html";
```

Utilize:

```
    window.location.replace("initial_page.html");
```

Ou:

```
    window.location.href = "initial_page.html";
```

Comment: Obrigado, essa mudança resolveu o problema, o código está 100% funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu utilizo este plugin, ele trata várias condições, eu troquei tambem `window.location.reload` por `window.location.href`:

https://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

Código retirado da página do plugin:

```
 $.idleTimer(10000);

    $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
     // executado quando o usuário ficar inativo, aqui você pode por o redirecionamento
        window.location.href= "initial_page.html";
    });


    $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
     // executado quando o usuário voltar a ficar ativo
    });

    // para parar o timer
    $.idleTimer('destroy');
```